# Laravel Job waits until exec is finished

Tags: php, laravel, queue, exec, jobs

I've problem with Laravel Jobs.
In `handle()` method I have `exec('php background_script.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');` -
laravel after this doesn't go to the next job from queue, but waits for the end of script executed in my `background_script.php` file and then process next job.
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

With `php artisan queue:work` it works, with `queue:listen` not.